# Elasticsearch: Retrieve all documents from a group where one document matches a criterion

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using Elasticsearch to store "events" in my system ("retrieved some data", "analyzed some data", ...). These events all have at least a `groupId` string field.

What I'd like to do is search for all events matching a criterion on some of the other fields, but return all events in the event group.

For example: give me all events that have timestamp `2017-07-20T12:43`. For each event `e` in the result, give me all events `e2` where `e.groupId = e2.groupId`.

The simplest solution would of course be two queries: one for the `groupIds` and another one for all events with those `groupIds`. But that sounds cumbersome. Is it possible using one Elasticsearch query? Or is there a more clever workaround? It's possible for me to change the document structure (it's not fixed yet).

I'm using Elasticsearch 2.3.0.

Comment: Probably it is not what you want but if it is possible you can try to change the structure to keep these events as a nested object. then you can search by any field inside and return parent object.

Comment: I am not sure if i understood the question correctly but if you know the value of e2.groupID before you actually execute the search, this could simply be done by filtering the results using a bool query.